# django как выполнить for new in news только 3 раза

Tags: python, django

В общем-то, проблема описана в заголовке: как цикл `for new in news` ограничить до первых 3х раз и, соответственно, вывести только первые 3 значения.
Для наглядности код оч простой, по типу:

```
{% for new in news %}
    <a href="{{ new.id }}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: может можно как-то из джанго в js передать? я просто фронт, вообще не знаю его. news[index] не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
{% for new in news %}
    {% if forloop.counter < 4 %}
        <a href="{{ new.id }}"></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: просто если будет их там тысячи, он будет проверять все. как можно насильно его остановить?

Comment: но решение хорошее, заработало. это уже хоть что-то. спасибо)

Comment: Здесь встроенный в шаблонизатор счётчик как раз и не даёт выводить больше 3-х элементов. По хорошему, вам лучше во views.py в вашей функции передавать ровно 3 значения вместо огромного списка, тогда и в шаблоне мудрить не придётся.

Comment: а во views.py как их можно обрезать до 3х не подскажите?

Comment: и да, он выведет ровно 3, я даже проверила, но цикл будет все равно работать эту тысячу раз, проверяя каждый раз, что оно меньше 4 - это повышает нагрузку

Comment: 'news': News.objects.order_by('-publish_date') - это из views.py

Comment: Можете попробовать добавить к запросу срез до 3-го значения: News.objects.order_by('-publish_date')[:3]

Comment: к сожалению, не сработало(

Comment: Это странно, у меня работает. Проверьте, туда ли вы дописали [:3] и то ли, что надо, передаёте в context.

Comment: да, извиняюсь. почистила кеш, заработало) спасибо